# Get a String from XamlWriter.Save(object obj, Stream stream)

Tags: c#, stream, xamlwriter

Can i get back a string from the `XamlWriter.Save(myBF, stream)`? I need it so save the string in my database. What i have to change on the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978067/wpf-can-binaryformatter-serialize-flowdocument-instance) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) and pass that as the second parameter to XamlWriter.Save().

Then you just need to call `StringWriter.ToString()` to get the string.