# Serialize FlowDocument type to binary file - wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I serialize FlowDocument types and save as binary file? I am new to WPF and trying to serialize an object which has FlowDocument, the value of which I want to get from a RichTextBox control. A sample class is like this-

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuAnalysisDTO

{
    public FlowDocument Item { get; set; }

    public FlowDocument Deduction { get; set; }

}
```

I used "BinaryFormatter" to serialize and get an error as-  'Type 'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument' em.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument'  is not marked as serializable.'

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978067/1136211

Comment: Thanks! I have seen it. But I wanted to save a nested object which would contain many such fields into a single file. One option I tried is to change the type of object to byte[] and convert each FlowDocument at the time of assignment to the object. And doing the revere when I deserialize it. Checking if any other easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the link provided by Clemens, you can use the build-in feature of the `FlowDocument`:

```
private FlowDocument SaveAndLoadRtfDocumentExample(FlowDocument document)
{ 
  // Save 

  // Convert the FlowDocument to RTF formatted file
  var documentRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);

  using (var outputStream = new FileStream("[Destination_File_Path]", File.OpenOrCreate))
  {
    documentRange.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
  }

  // Load

  // Convert the RTF formatted file stream to a FlowDocument     
  var blankDocument = new FlowDocument();
  var blankDocumentRange = new TextRange(blankDocument.ContentStart, blankDocument.ContentEnd);

  using (var inputStream = new FileStream("[Source_File_Path]", File.Open))
  {
    blankDocumentRange.Load(inputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    return blankDocument;
  }
}
```